# set.seed with R 2.15.2

Tags: r, random, statistics

My understanding is that using `set.seed` ensures reproducibility but this is not the case with the following R code in `R 2.15.2`. Am I missing something here?

```
set.seed(12345)
rnorm(5)
[1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875
 rnorm(5)
[1] -1.8179560  0.6300986 -0.2761841 -0.2841597 -0.9193220
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`set.seed()` reinitializes the [random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

```
set.seed(12345)
rnorm(5)
[1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875

set.seed(12345)
rnorm(5)
[1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875

set.seed(12345)
rnorm(5)
[1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875
```

Answer (score 13):

Any call that uses the random number generator will change the current seed, even if you've manually set it with `set.seed`.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- .Random.seed # get the current seed
runif(10) # uses random number generator, so changes current seed
y <- .Random.seed
identical(x, y) # FALSE
```

As @StephanKolassa demonstrates, you'd have to reset the seed before each use of the random number generator to guarantee that it uses the same one each time.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth underlining here that the *sequence* of numbers is still reproducible each time you set the seed, because of this reinitialisation.

So although with each subsequent call to e.g. `rnorm` you're getting different answers to each call, **you're still going to get the same sequence of numbers from the point the seed was set**.

E.g., per the original question:

```
set.seed(12345)
rnorm(5)
[1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875
rnorm(5)
[1] -1.8179560  0.6300986 -0.2761841 -0.2841597 -0.9193220
```

Produces the same sequence of 10 numbers as:

```
set.seed(12345)
rnorm(10)
[1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875
-1.8179560  0.6300986 -0.2761841 -0.2841597 -0.9193220
```

Or

```
set.seed(12345)
rnorm(7)
[1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875
-1.8179560  0.6300986
rnorm(3)
[1] -0.2761841 -0.2841597 -0.9193220
```

Or whatever series of calls to `rnorm`.

The point here is that **if you set the seed once at the start of a script you will get the same set of random numbers generated each time you run that whole script**, while getting a different set of numbers from each random number generator call within the code. This is because you are running on the same sequence from that seed at the start. This can be a good thing, and it means that if you want a reproducible script you can set the seed once at the beginning.