# Use of set.seed() in statistics

Tags: r, statistics

This is an elementary question so I apologize if I am missing something obvious. I'm in an advanced statistics class, albeit the first at my university to use R software. The question is primarily to get us used to using R and asks us to calculate the log of the square root of 125 and to use the set.seed() function. I am confused about the set.seed aspect. I understand that it is used as a random number generator in simulations but I don't understand where it is applied within the code. This is what I did.

```
125 %>%
log() %>%
sqrt() %>%
set.seed(100)
```

Is this how it is supposed to be used?

Comment: The `set.seed` call comes *before* you do any functions which have a random element. And you wouldn't chain `%>%` it. See the examples here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380096/set-seed-with-r-2-15-2 for a typical usage. There is nothing random about `sqrt(log(125))` however - I'm thinking the homework might have more parts to it or expect you to do the calculation in some other way if `set.seed` is asked for explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

No. Someone will probably give a fuller answer, but:

- `set.seed()` does not affect the `log()` or `sqrt()` operations at all. Maybe this was supposed to be a two-part question ("(1) calculate the log of the square root of 125; (2) use `set.seed()` to set the state of the pseudo-random number generator")
- You *can* use the pipe (`%>%`) operator in this way to compose the `log()` and `sqrt()` functions, but (unless you have been specifically instructed to do it this way, for some reason) it's overkill. You really might as well write it in the more "normal" way `log(sqrt(125))`.